# Rounding the corners of an SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I'm using a package that generates a rectangular Treemap with this structure:

- **svg** (wrapper with width=100% and height=100%)

  - **svg** (the outer rectangle of the Treemap, also width=100% and height=100%)

    - **g** (one for each Treemap node)

      - **rect**
      - **clipPath**
      - **text**

[image: svg element]
I need to **round the four corners of the entire Treemap** (not the rx ry of each rect within).

Is it possible to do that by creating a clipPath either as a child of the wrapper or the inner svg that defines a rounded rectangle? If so, can it expose whatever the background color is behind the svg?

**UPDATE:** @web-tiki - here's what the code looks like...

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" style="border-radius: 4px;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <!-- ... -->
```

Looks great on Safari and Firefox but Chrome appears to ignore it. Wondering if it's a combination of Carbon Charts Treemap and Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use the `border-radius` CSS property on the svg wrapper element. It will allow you to **clip round corners on your svg element and expose the background color behind** the svg.
Here is an example :

```css
body {
  background: darkorange;
}

#wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:10px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<svg id="wrapper" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <svg>
    <rect fill="teal" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
   </svg>
</svg>
```

On a side note, you can also wrap the entire svg inside a div and apply the `border-radius` on that div like this :

```css
body {
  background: darkorange;
}

#wrapper {
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <svg>
      <rect fill="teal" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
     </svg>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Such an easy solution. This works well in Safari but Google Chrome doesn't seem to display the svg with the border-radius. Perhaps a bug in the latest Chrome?

Comment: @nstuyvesant I just tested my example on chrome and it works fine. What code did you test ?

Answer (score 0):

Found I could add this to the wrapper svg to get the effect I wanted:

```xml
<defs>
  <clipPath id="smallBox">
    <path d="M 0 4 A 4 4 0 0 1 4 0 L 446 0 A 4 4 0 0 1 450 4 L 450 346 A 4 4 0 0 1 446 350 L 4 350 A 4 4 0 0 1 0 346 Z"/>
  </clipPath>
</defs>
```

then added `style="clip-path: url(#smallBox);"` to the inner svg.

The path was generated with this code (source: https://gist.github.com/danielpquinn/dd966af424030d47e476)

```js
const roundedRect = (w, h, r) => 
    'M 0 ' + r
    + ' A ' + r + ' ' + r + ' 0 0 1 ' + r + ' 0'
    + ' L ' + (w - r) + ' 0'
    + ' A ' + r + ' ' + r + ' 0 0 1 ' + w + ' ' + r
    + ' L ' + w + ' ' + (h - r)
    + ' A ' + r + ' ' + r + ' 0 0 1 ' + (w - r) + ' ' + h
    + ' L ' + r + ' ' + h
    + ' A ' + r + ' ' + r + ' 0 0 1 0 ' + (h - r)
    + ' Z'

console.log(roundedRect(450,350,4))
```